# maintaing object constancy in transistioning donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 but getting there.

I'm having trouble maintaining object constancy with differently-sized datasets. 
I have it set up here. (I'm having trouble to get jsfiddle to work)

http://bricbracs.com/test/

The initial chart has three arcs. When you click on a segment arc it updates with new data from (using a nested function) and is supposed to return four data elements with four corresponding arcs. As you can see it's returning only three arcs. What is the best way and simplest way to get this to work corrcetly so that it shows four segemnts?

I have seen this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681842. But I am using a nested function with a rollup function.

Here is a csv file ( a simplified version, probably not necessary).

```
status,dept,city,points
temp,finance,New York,33
contract,HR,London,12
contract,HR,New York,11
casual,shop,London,43
temp,sales,New York,14
contract,shop,Paris,51
temp,finance,London,7
contract,office,New York,61
contract,shop,London,31
temp,office,New York,16
contract,office,London,19
temp,finance,London,7
contract,office,New York,61
contract,sales,London,31
temp,finance,New York,16
contract,sales,Paris,19
temp,sales,New York,11
```

Here is the d3 script. Thanks in advance

```
  var data1
  var data2
   var datax
  var width = 960,
  height = 500,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
   svg.style("cursor","pointer")

d3.csv("data4.csv", function(error, data) {
 datax=data
  var data1 = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.city ;
    })
    .rollup(function(d) {
      return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
        return g.points;
      });
    }).entries(data);

   var path = svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(pie(data1))
    .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "arc");

  path.on("click", function() {       
  data2=datax
    change(data2)
 })
 path.transition()
.duration(500)
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.data.key );
   })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .each(function(d) {
    this._current = d;
  })

function arcTween(a) {
var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
this._current = i(0);
return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
 };
}
 function change(data) {
 data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.city == "New York"; });
 var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.dept;
    })
    .rollup(function(d) {
      return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
        return g.points;
      });
    }).entries(data);
path.data(pie(data));
path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
}

});
```

Comment: You need to include the enter/append stuff in your `change` function.

Comment: You have some other interesting problems as well in arranging the transition. You need to do it in two steps I think: first with new entries set to zero; then with the true angle. You need to anticipate the maximum segments you will need and pad the data with zeros for the shorter sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy is to transition the update selection (the object returned by `.data()`), and then add the enter selection (the object returned by `.enter()`) after a synchronised delay...

```js
        var datax
        var data1

        var enterAntiClockwise = {
            startAngle: Math.PI * 2,
            endAngle: Math.PI * 2
        };

        var width = 960,
            height = 500,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(radius - 70);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function (d) {
                return d.values;
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
        svg.style("cursor", "pointer")



        d3.csv("data4.csv", function (error, data) {
            datax = data
            //data1=data
            // data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.city == "New York"; });

            var data1 = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) {
                    return d.city;
                })
                .rollup(function (d) {
                    return d3.sum(d, function (g) {
                        return g.points;
                    });
                }).entries(data);

            var path = render(data1)

            path.on("click", function () {
                data2 = datax
                render(change(data2));
            })

            function arcTween(a) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
                this._current = i(0);
                return function (t) {
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
            }

            function change(data) {
                data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.city == "New York"; });
                var newData = d3.nest()
                                .key(function (d) {
                                    return d.dept;
                                })
                                .rollup(function (d) {
                                    return d3.sum(d, function (g) {
                                        return g.points;
                                    });
                                }).entries(data);
                return newData
            }

            function render(data) {
                var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path").data(pie)
                path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
                path.enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("class", "arc")
                        .transition().duration(0).delay(750)
                        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                            return color(d.data.key);
                        })
                        .attr("d", arc)
                        .each(function (d) {
                            this._current = d;
                        })
                return path;
            }

        });
```

(this technique is based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jonsadka/fa05f8d53d4e8b5f262e), I added the delay and adapted it to your example by nailing it to a piece of wood...)

The ultimate strategy perhaps is to create zero pie slices in the layout so that they transition from zero on enter...

```js
var enterAntiClockwise = {
   startAngle: Math.PI * 2,
   endAngle: Math.PI * 2
  };

  var width = window.innerWidth,
   height = window.innerHeight - 20,
   radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 * 0.8;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
   .outerRadius(radius)
   .innerRadius(radius - 20);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
   .sort(null)
   .value(function (d) {
    return d.values;
   });
  pie.zero = pie([{ values: 1 }, { values: 0 }])[1];  //zero pie slice

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
  svg.style("cursor", "pointer")

  d3.csv("data4u.csv", function (error, data) {
   data = data || d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text())
   var data1 = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) {
          return d.city;
        })
        .rollup(function (d) {
          return d3.sum(d, function (g) {
            return g.points;
          });
        }).entries(data),

       path = render(data1);

   path.on("click", function () {
     render(change(data));
   });

   function arcTween(a) {
     var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
     this._current = i(0);
     return function (t) {
       return arc(i(t));
     };
   };

   function change(data) {
    data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.city == "New York"; });
    var newData = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) {
         return d.dept;
        })
        .rollup(function (d) {
         return d3.sum(d, function (g) {
          return g.points;
         });
        }).entries(data);
    return newData
   }
   
   function render(data) {
    var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path").data(pie)
    var enter = path.enter();
    enter.append("path")
     .attr("class", "arc")
     .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
      return color(d.data.key);
     })
     .attr("d", function (d, i) {
      this._current = pie.zero;
      return arc(pie.zero);
      });

    path.transition().duration(1500).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs

    return path;
   }

  });
```

```css
#csv {
  display: none;
 }
svg { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="csv">status,dept,city,points
  temp,finance,New York,33
  contract,HR,London,12
  contract,HR,New York,11
  casual,shop,London,43
  temp,sales,New York,14
  contract,shop,Paris,51
  temp,finance,London,7
  contract,office,New York,61
  contract,shop,London,31
  temp,office,New York,16
  contract,office,London,19
  temp,finance,London,7
  contract,office,New York,61
  contract,sales,London,31
  temp,finance,New York,16
  contract,sales,Paris,19
  temp,sales,New York,11  </div>
```

Comment: @ronmac, but wait, there's more...  don't forget to accept the answer ;)